# "Loading more" indicator issue in Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, question-lists

**Issue:**

As far as I know, "loading more" action is required only when there are more results possible (for example, feed screen) but while in particular site's question list, if there is a single item or two items, then list view should not allow or suppress "loading more" action.

**App version: 0.1.11**

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Try to search any tag/keyword which should give you 1-2 questions in result. For example: Nokia apps
2. Try to pull up the questions list view and release it to load more items (loading more items actions).

P.S. I use `Nokia apps` just for testing and illustrating issue :)

[image: loading indicator]

Comment: Shouldn't we be allowed to refresh search results, for checking whether there are new questions/posts that match the search? Maybe I don't understand the issue here.

Comment: issue is in loading more items. For example loading more items in Feed screen, it shows you loading at bottom only when you reach at bottom and it gets started loading more items (I.e. Next page items)

Comment: I think it's because of how ListView (or RecyclerView) that SE App used works: basically when fetching data (include refreshing), it will always append the loading indicator at the end of the list (until now, v1.0.83). Not sure if it's a bug.

Comment: But I think when you do pull to refresh, ideal practice is to make listview invisible and make it visible as soon as data is fetched successfully from API, if no data then empty view!